# Oracle PL/SQL anonymous block stopped working after modified into procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have written an anonymous block which works fine. SQL%ROWCOUNT tells me that n rows had been processed:

```
declare
    user_list varchar2(100) := 'TESTUSER';
    v_test number;
begin
execute immediate '
    insert into config_all_objects (
    owner
    , object_name
    , object_type
    , created
    , status
    )
    select
    owner
    , object_name
    , object_type
    , created
    , status
    from all_objects
    where regexp_like(owner, ''^('||user_list||')$'', ''i'')'
    ;

    dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount);

end;
/
```

Then I changed it into stored procedure and when I run it 0 rows had been processed:

```
create or replace procedure p_test2(
    user_list varchar2
)
as
    v_test number;
    v_user_list varchar2(100) := user_list;
begin
execute immediate '
    insert into config_all_objects (
    owner
    , object_name
    , object_type
    , created
    , status
    )
    select
    owner
    , object_name
    , object_type
    , created
    , status
    from all_objects
    where regexp_like(owner, ''^('||v_user_list||')$'', ''i'')'
    ;

    dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount);

end;
/

begin p_test2 (user_list => 'TESTUSER');
end;
/
```

Why is that?

I checked that the execute immediate command is exactly same in both cases.

Also I made sure that the user used to run both codes (eiauto) has direct grant on that table...

```
grant select on all_objects to eiauto;
```

Here is the DDL for config_all_objects table:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE CONFIG_ALL_OBJECTS
                ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
                as select 
                owner
                , object_name
                , object_type
                , created
                , status
                from all_objects
                where 1=2
```

EDIT:
I really can't answer this but I found a workaround: instead of ALL_OBJECTS use DBA_OBJECTS table which works fine.

And this also brings me to the possible cause. From Oracle documentation:

> ALL_OBJECTS describes all objects **accessible to the current user**.
>
> DBA_OBJECTS describes all objects in the database.

I guess it is somehow related to the privileges...

Comment: Work's fine for me, have a look : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2c008e8da162d8d2bc4444061174fed1

Comment: Hm, interesting. When I run them for user PUBLIC, they both give same results.
When I run them for user HR, procedure returns 0 while anonym. block returns correct number.
When I run them for user SYS, procedure return 2422 while anonym. block returns 9087 records. What can I infer from that?

Comment: I see some issue in where regexp_like(owner, ''^('||v_user_list||')$'', ''i'') ... the values are not passed from parameter ... what is the condition you are looking for?

Comment: That was me just being hopeless, so I tried to pass the value to a variable... But it did not have any effect.

Comment: What happens if you do it "properly" as `execute immediate '
    insert into ... WHERE regexp_like(owner, '^:userList$', ''i'')' USING user_list;`?
    ;

Comment: Nothing changes. The procedure still returns 0 (for HR user) and less records (2422 for SYS) than anonymous block (9087 for SYS).
I guess the issue must be somehow related to the privileges...

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit surely "properly" would be `insert into ... where regexp_like(owner, '^'||userlist$, 'i')`?! *{;-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because of the nature of "ALL_" dictionary views.
A stored procedure by default runs with the "invoker's rights".

The
AUTHID CURRENT_USER
clause might solve this problem.

Something like this:

```
create or replace procedure p_test2(
    user_list varchar2
) AUTHID CURRENT_USER
as
var1 NUMBER;
begin
 --code here
end p_test2;
```

Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21639/accesscntl.htm#TTPLS275